# int isn't a type

Tags: sql, flutter, dart

on passing the version to the on create method and integer(int) of the id that i want to fetch from the database,i get an error saying "int isn't a type"[error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFT61.png)

```
class NewsDbProvider {
  Database db;

  int() async {

    Directory documentsDirectory =await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    final path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "items.db");

    db = await openDatabase(
        path,
        version: 1,
        onCreate: (Database newDb,int version){
          newDb.execute("""
            CREATE TABLE Items
            (

            )
            """);
        }
    );
  }

  fetchItem(int id) async{
    db.query(
      "Items",
      columns: null,
      where: 'id = ?',
      whereArgs: {id},
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You named a method of `NewsDbProvider` as `int`, which is why the keyword isn't being recognised anymore. Try renaming it.

Comment: Thanks, i nearly pulled my hair out. Clumsy me